# Should lru cache be used for a function with DB calls

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I had a method in my code with look really long to execute. This function is called around 30 times for different currencies, It fetches some data for those currencies from database (psql) .Now I added lru_cache decorator for that function. It decreased execution time very much but I have a doubt that will this method now return old data (values in database may change). My code structure is something like this.

```
@lru_cache
def fetch_from_db(symbol):
    #data fetched from db
    return data

for symbol in allSymbols:
    list.append(fetch_from_db(symbol))
    return list
```

I want to make sure that this data is correct all time.

I actually did some tests. For my test data was always new but If anyone thinks that this might break somewhere, Please Do tell

Thanks

Comment: We can't tell you without knowing what is a "symbol" in context

Comment: Symbol is like (USD , AUS) they are just elements in database of which information is saved to database (like fees,current conversion etc.) I am fetching this information from DB by symbol name

Comment: So a symbol is a tuple of 2 strings?

Comment: No, Symbol is just a string "USD" then I run DB query (SELECT * FROM DB WHERE NAME = "USD")

Comment: You cannot be sure that a cached value is always the latest (that defeats the purpose). You can, however, use Django's cache framework instead to limit caching duration to, say, 10 minutes to make sure that it is refreshed at worst every 10 minutes. I would also optimise this further by making a single db call to get all the currencies in advance and cache that list.